# Image gallery with different image heights: Removing the gaps between

Tags: javascript, image, padding, image-gallery

I'm working with this Script:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp

My problem is that my images have different heights and I don't want that gap between. How is it possible to remove them? The gap height should be always same.

Thank you!

Love

Comment: google "masonry layout"

Comment: Isn't it possible to take the script from w3schools?